# Add file to subversion, while automatically adding parent directory node(s) if not added already

Tags: svn

When I want to add a file in a directory using

```
svn add directory/file.extension
```

and directory has not been added yet, I get an error that says that directory's node cannot be found and needs to be added first. So I can do

```
svn add directory --depth=empty
svn add directory/file.extension
```

Can I automate the last two steps? Perhaps with a fitting parameter to svn add?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the `--parents` option to `svn add` to add intermediate parents:

```
svn add --parents directory/file
```